# python if...elif always not working

Tags: python

Sorry for posting such a naive question, but I'm just not able to figure this out. I have written following conditional statements:

```
if taxon == "Bracelets":
    catId = "178785"
elif taxon == "Kids Earrings" or "Earrings":
    catId = "177591"
elif taxon == "Mangalsutras":
    catId = "177595"
elif taxon == "Necklaces" or "Necklace Sets":
    catId = "177597"
elif taxon == "Kids Pendants" or "Pendants":
    catId = "177592"
elif taxon == "Pendant Sets":
    catId = "177593"
elif taxon == "Anklets":
    catId = "178788"
elif taxon == "Toe Rings":
    catId = "178787"
elif taxon == "Rings":
    catId = "177590"
else:
    print "no match\n"
```

But no matter what the value of taxon is, its always falling in the second condition i.e.

```
elif taxon == "Kids Earrings" or "Earrings":
    catId = "177591"
```

and therefore, the value of catId remains `177591`.

Comment: `elif taxon == "Kids Earrings" or taxon == "Earrings":` otherwise the 2nd condition will always be true

Comment: @MartijnPieters : True. But, it was tough to find it as the name of the question does not suggest anything abt the content

Comment: That's alright, this is an issue many beginners run into without realizing what is going wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be

```
elif taxon == "Kids Earrings" or taxon == "Earrings":
```

Your original code tests the truth value of `"Earrings"` rather than whether `taxon` has the value `"Earrings"`

```
>>> bool("Earrings")
True
```

A better way to structure this is with a dictionary:

```
id_map = {}
id_map["Bracelets"] = "178785"
id_map["Earrings"] = "177591"
id_map["Kids Earrings"] = "177591"
# etc
```

then later you can do

```
id_map[taxon]
```

This also lends itself better to storage in a configuration file or database, to avoid hard-coding the values in your Python code.

Answer (score 7):

Others have already given the syntactical answer to your problem.

My answer is to change this ugly code to use a dictionary lookup.  For example:

```
taxes = {"Bracelets": 178785, "Necklaces": 177597, "Necklace Sets": 177597}
#etc
```

Then you use

```
catId = taxes[taxon]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this idiom:

```
elif taxon in ("Kids Earrings", "Earrings"):
```

Comment: That's actually can cause some problems i think, if taxon is "Kids" for example.

Comment: It will not cause problem.

Comment: You are right +1, I didn't know about that option.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's always true since it evaluates for Boolean `True`, it checks if the string is empty.

Change to:

```
if taxon == "Bracelets":
    catId = "178785"
elif taxon == "Kids Earrings" or taxon == "Earrings":
    catId = "177591"
elif taxon == "Mangalsutras":
    catId = "177595"
elif taxon == "Necklaces" or taxon == "Necklace Sets":
    catId = "177597"
elif taxon == "Kids Pendants" or taxon == "Pendants":
    catId = "177592"
elif taxon == "Pendant Sets":
    catId = "177593"
elif taxon == "Anklets":
    catId = "178788"
elif taxon == "Toe Rings":
    catId = "178787"
elif taxon == "Rings":
    catId = "177590"
else:
    print "no match\n
```

In a personal note i would use python `dict` is really good instead of if else:

```
options = {"option1": "value1", "option2": "value2".....}
```

Answer (score 1):

This condition:

`taxon == "Kids Earrings" or "Earrings"`

looks like

`(taxon == "Kids Earrings") or "Earrings"`

which is always true because `"Earrings"` evaluates true (is a non-empty string).

You'd like to do:

`taxon in ("Earrings, "Kids Earrings")`

or just write several conditions:

`taxon == "Earrings" or taxon == "Kids Earrings"`

or perhaps:

`taxon.endswith("Earrings")`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
elif taxon in ("Kids Earrings", "Earrings"):
```

Answer (score 0):

the second condition isn't checked against a variable. like this it makes no sense!
try it this way:

```
...
elif taxon == "Kids Earrings" or taxon == "Earrings":
    catId = "177591"
...
```